# How to put multiple items in one column?

Tags: html, css, video

I am new to designing websites and I had a question. I am designing the webpage to have 3 columns (fluid layout), and I was wondering how to make it so I can have multiple items in each column? What I am trying to accomplish with this webpage is to embed 9 youtube videos on this webpage, and I want 3 rows, so I need to be able to put 3 stacked over each other in each column. And I'm trying to figure out how to center each video in the columns without using the deprecated center  tag.
Thanks

Heres the coding:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ajt8/

it looks messed up in the preview on that site so if you copy and paste it out and look in the browser it should look normal

Comment: What have you tried? Can you put an example up on http://jsbin.com or http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Heres the coding:

http://jsfiddle.net/5Ajt8/

it looks messed up in the preview on that site so if you copy and paste it out and look in the browser it should look normal

Answer (score 0):

Put a table inside one of the columns.

Comment: He hasn't said much about what he's tried, so my guess is he hasn't realized he could do something like this with html.

Comment: i tried using a table, but it made all of the columns overlap each other.

Answer (score 0):

You can try either `text-align:center;` on the container for each column.

You can also wrap each video in its own `div` and give that `div` a `margin:0 auto`

Answer (score 0):

By declaring margin-left and margin-right as auto you can center
a block element within it's container.

http://jsfiddle.net/L74yt/

Comment: Hi Jeff! Are you from Henderson? Graduate back in '88?

Comment: No Sorry, I was only 1 year old in 1988. Haha.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/marvo/NBgKZ/

Structure:

```
<div class="page">
<div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item #1</div>
    <div class="item">Item #2</div>
    <div class="item">Item #3</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item #1</div>
    <div class="item">Item #2</div>
    <div class="item">Item #3</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="item">Item #1</div>
    <div class="item">Item #2</div>
    <div class="item">Item #3</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Styles:

```
.page {
    width : 640px;
}

.column {
    background-color : #e0e0e0;
    width : 200px;
    float : left;
    border : 1px solid black;
}

.item {
    background-color : yellow;
    width : 100px;
    border : 1px dashed red;
    margin : 5px auto 5px auto;
}
```